# Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName

Tags: windows-10, jdk, elasticsearch, jvm

When i try to install sonarqube on windows 10, elasticsearch give me this error:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-7.9.1\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:14 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019-09-26 18:56:16,394 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName
jvm 1    | 2019-09-26 18:56:16,439 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfAccumulatedFileCount
jvm 1    | 2019-09-26 18:56:16,439 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfFileName
jvm 1    | 2019-09-26 18:56:16,444 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction for element Delete: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:103)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:87)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.generateParameters(PluginBuilder.java:254)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:136)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:234)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:127)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:302)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019-09-26 18:56:16,448 main ERROR Null object returned for Delete in DefaultRolloverStrategy.
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:20 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.09.26 18:56:20 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I try to:

- add jvm parameter: `-Duser.language=en` and nothing changed.
- run as administrator and nothing changed.
- run as not adminisrator and again nothing changed.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any other relevant solutions. So what can I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Albin i try to add jvm parameter: `-Duser.language=en` and nothing changed. Try to run as administrator and nothing changed. Try to run as not adminisrator and again nothing changed. I looked at all the resources on the internet but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Okey thank you for answer.

Comment: I doubt you looked at `all` internet sources. And it's a good idea to make you question as reader friendly as possible. See my changes.

Comment: @Albin Actually, you're right. I noticed that I was very repulsive and smarty-pants. Sorry for that. Thank you for changes. It was better like this. By the way sorry my english.